# Clearing text displayed on a Message widget in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing a GUI app using tkinter that prints messages to the user via the Message widget (which is used as an output display by the GUI). The app checks if the paper size of a document is A4 or not (via a series of loops and functions) and then prints appropriate messages.

The code was written using Python (3.10) on PyCharm (Community Edition 2021.3.3). The modules used are: tkinter (8.6) and python-docx (0.8.11).

One of the GUI buttons should allow to clear the displayed messages. I have done this previously with the Text widget in tkinter using the following code:

```
clear_btn = tk.Button(root, command=lambda: output_display.delete(1.0, tk.END))
```

I tried to do something similar with the addition of a Message widget. But that command is not supported by the Message widget.

I would like to know if it is possible to clear the text displayed by a Message widget. If so, how could this be implemented?

I was considering replacing the Text widget with a Message widget as the latter allows to resize text more effectively (i.e., when the text runs over the width of the window).

Comment: try to understand what you need - isn't tk.Message.configure(text="") doable for your case?

Comment: Add single or double quote ('1.0', tk.END)